# Find the area of ​the non-convex pentagonal region AEIDCA.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, area, plane-geometry

For reference:

> In triangle $ABC$, the interior angle bisectors $AD$ and $CE$ are drwan which intersect at $I$. If $\angle B = 60^\circ$ and the area of triangular region $AIC$ is $A$, calculate the area of ​​the non-convex pentagonal region $AEIDCA$. (Answer: $2A$)

[image]

My progress:

I found many relationships but the main one is missing

$\theta+\alpha=60^\circ$

$\frac{S[ABC]}{S[ABD]}=\frac{AC}{AB}$

$\frac{S[ACE]}{S[BCE}=\frac{AC}{BC}$

$\frac{A}{S[AEI]}=\frac{AC}{AE}$

$\frac{A}{S[CDI]}=\frac{AC}{CD} $

$\triangle ABC: \frac{AB}{BD}=\frac{AC}{CD}$

$\triangle AEC: \frac{AE}{EI}=\frac{AC}{CI}$

$\triangle CDA: \frac{CD}{DI}=\frac{AC}{AI}$

...??

Comment: The figure just folds. Fold at $CI$ so $CD$ is on $AC$ and fold at $AI$ so $AE$ is on $AC$. Then $IE$ and $ID$ coincide as they are going to be both angle bisectors of $\angle AIC$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X\in AC$ such that $\angle AIX=\angle XIC=60^\circ$. Observe that $\angle EIA=180^\circ -120^\circ =60^\circ =\angle XIA$, and by definition $\angle IAE=\alpha =\angle IAX$. Therefore, from angle-side-angle criterion we get that the triangles $AIE$ and $AIX$ are congruent. Hence $S[AIX]=S[AIE]$. Analogously, we find that $S[CIX]=S[CID]$. 
Finally\begin{align*}S[AEIDC] & =S[AIE]+S[AIX]+S[CID]+S[CIX] \\
& =2\cdot S[AIX]+2\cdot S[CIX] \\
& =2\cdot (S[AIX]+S[CIX]) \\
& =2\cdot S[AIC] \\
& =2\cdot A
\end{align*}as wanted.